# Почему разметка в DialogFragment обрезается

Tags: android, android-layout

У меня есть разметка для `DialogFragment`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:background="@color/white">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"

        android:fillViewport="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/ready"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

И сам `DialogFragment`:

```
public class ForwardersDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_forwarders, container);
    }
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что диалог получается обрезанным (справа, если присмотреться, видно, что ни кнопка, ни текстовое поле не заканчиваются):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При запуске этой же разметки в активности, а не диалоге, все влазит, но и визуальна разметки получается больше (в ширину). Почему, при открытии разметки в диалоге, она обрезается?

---

P.S. Нет, Юрий, я тестирую не в превью, а на реальном устройстве. :D

Comment: А зачем вы проставили в `dp` ширину/высоту? Поставьте Match_Parent и всё...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, тогда некрасиво выходит. Во-первых, окно "сжимается", а, во-вторых, в окне будет очень много разных вьюшек, нужен четкий размер.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очевидно, что ширина диалога на этом вашем устройстве меньше 300dp, потому и обрезается. На других устройствах будет другой лимит.

Лучше бы вам сейчас остановиться и заново продумать разметку так, чтобы в ней не было абсолютных значений. Иначе, чтобы всё заработало, вам надо подобрать будет такие значения ширины/высоты для каждого возможного размера экрана чтобы оно влезало.